# How to calculate win probability for each team in a Round of 16 knockout tournament

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

Let's say there are 16 teams in a standard Round of 16 bracket. The initial matchups are known (A plays B, C plays D, etc.). We know the probability for each possible matchup (A has a 54% chance of beating B, 58% chance of beating C, etc.) So is there a formula to determine the win% for each team?

By the time you get through 5 rounds, there are so many possible conflagrations, so I couldn't figure out a reasonable way to make a grid or spreadsheet of every possible combination of results. So I have been just running a simulator that randomizes each game and plays out the whole tournament thousands of times. But I feel like there should be some more precise formula to get a more direct answer. I just don't know how to build it.

Comment: I would think that simulation is the way to go here.  As you say, the branching gets pretty messy.

Comment: I suspect there are 5160960 patterns of games (times 2027025 if you do not know the round of 16 matchups) so simulation makes sense

Comment: Actually 5 million calculations is not that many. I'm not using a chalk board and abacus, I have a computer. I guess I just need to figure out a way to plot all that.

Comment: I take that back. I have no idea how to write a loop or something that would create the 5 million scenarios.

Comment: Ok I'm missing something. If there are 8 games in the first round, then 4 games in the second round, then 2 in the semi final plus the final, this is a total of 15 games. 2^15 = 32,768 total possible scenarios (not 5 million). Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: The number $5160960$ assumes nothing is known at all about the matchups in the second and subsequent rounds. (That is, the winner of $AB$ could play any of the other $7$ winners in the second round, etc.)

Comment: That’s not how a standard bracket works.

Comment: @MichaelT But the author said the initial matchups aka the games on round 16 are set. So neither of your answer( and Henry's) is correct.

Comment: @MemphisMeng I don't know what you mean. I asked the original question and yes, the first round is set. So there are 8 first round games, 4 second round, 2 semis and 1 final (15 games total). So the number of scenarios is 2^15. You are saying this is not correct but, if so, what is the correct answer?